# How to convert a list of lists to an array of lists?

Tags: r

I have a list of lists in R. I would like to convert it to an array of lists, but I only get an array of lists of lists:

```
r <- list(list(a=1, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=1.23),
          list(a=2, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=3.32),
          list(a=3, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=2.13),
          list(a=4, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=3.25),
          list(a=5, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=0.14),
          list(a=6, b=NULL, c=NULL, d=5.13))
x <- array(r, dim=c(3,2))
x[1,1] # now a list of length 1 containing an element which is a list with components a--d
```

As you can see, `x[1,1]` (for example) is now a list of lists, but the "outer" list is useless. I would rather like to have an array `y` with `y[i,j]` being `x[i,j][[1]]`. What's the best way to get this (using functions from base-R (no additional packages))?

I tried to use some `unlist()` hackery like `array(unlist(r, recursive=FALSE), dim=c(3,2))`, but that fails. `sapply(r, FUN=I)` at least gives a matrix... maybe that helps (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, by design.

Vector elements are by definition vectors of length 1, and arrays/matrices are still vectors with dimensions.

Lists are themselves generic vectors, so they can be elements of other lists (or arrays, or matrices), but only if they themselves have length 1.

BTW this is the reason why using [ ] to select an object contained in a list only returns a list of size 1 containing the object, and not the actual object, which you need to get using [[ ]].

So the answer is, there's really no way to get rid of the "outer" list.

For details, consult the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Vector-objects) manual.

Comment: -1 `[[` works with `array`s as well as `list`s, so there is a way. also, `list`s of length zero can certainly be elements in other `list`s and `array`s.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Both `[[` and `[` are generic and can be used with various classes, this doesn't suggest anything. For details, `?Extract`. Also, if `a <- list(list(), list())`, then `a[1]` still returns a list of length one containing an empty list, while `a[[1]]` returns the actual empty list. Which demonstrates that vector (or list, or array, etc) elements are _by default_ of size 1, and they may **in turn** contain objects of other types.

Comment: of course `[[` and `[` are generic. I don't understand the point you're making in the first sentence. Regarding the length of `list` elements, you're right, but this is a subtle point and you could make it clearer in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use double brackets, `x[[1,1]]`.

Comment: This is equivalent to `x[1,1][[1]]`, which is what the person asking the question wanted to avoid using.

Comment: obviously. but it sounds like OP wants to avoid the inconvenience of typing 3 indexes and extra brackets.

Comment: Thanks very much, Matthew and Theodore, that clarified a lot.